# Paypal : Transfer money using API credentials

Tags: php, paypal

Can we transfer money from one Business account to other personal account using only API credentials?

As we want to call a script with API credentials of Business account to transfer money to other's personal account, without clicking on any Paypal Pay button.

Please help us out.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it I believe that your key to success lies with PayPal's [MassPay API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_masspay).  I am not intimately familiar with this but it because I haven't had to use it yet but on the surface it looks like it may do what you need.

With their other APIs and services you cannot transfer funds without logging into PayPal at some level.

Comment: Can you please tell where to get that MassPay API files? as we didn't get any API file over that link.

Comment: It's a REST API. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MassPay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/MassPay_API_Operation_NVP/).

This should help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But we didn't get API code .There is only documentation. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MassPay API to do this if you are just wanting to use your API credentials.  You can find a code example in [PayPal's Merchant SDK](http://paypal.github.io/).  There is an example in Ruby, Java, PHP, and .NET.  Also, another method to send funds to an account would be to use the Adaptive Payments API, but this requires you to submit an application on x.com and be approved to use it.